# async/await with ConfigureAwait's continueOnCapturedContext parameter and SynchronizationContext for asynchronous continuations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await, synchronizationcontext

I would like put the code first and then explain the situation and ask my question based on that:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        var result = await GetValuesAsync();
        Foo.Text += result;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetValuesAsync() {           

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

            var response = await httpClient
                .GetAsync("http://www.google.com")
                .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);


            // This is the continuation for the httpClient.GetAsync method.
            // We shouldn't get back to sync context here
            // Cuz the continueOnCapturedContext is set to *false*
            // for the Task which is returned from httpClient.GetAsync method
            var html = await GetStringAsync();

            // This is the continuation for the GetStringAsync method.
            // Should I get back to sync context here?
            // Cuz the continueOnCapturedContext is set to *true*
            // for the Task which is returned from GetStringAsync 

            // However, GetStringAsync may be executed in another thread
            // which has no knowledge for the sync context 
            // because the continueOnCapturedContext is set to *false*
            // for the Task which is returned from httpClient.GetAsync method.

            // But, on the other hand, GetStringAsync method also has a 
            // chance to be executed in the UI thread but we shouldn't be
            // relying on that. 
            html += "Hey...";
            Foo.Text = html;

            return html;
        }
    }

    public async Task<string> GetStringAsync() {

        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return "Done...";
    }
}
```

This is a fairly simple WPF sample which runs on .NET 4.5 and probably doesn't make a lot of sense but this should help me explain my situation.

I have a button on the screen which has an asynchronous click event. When you look at the `GetValuesAsync` code, you will see the usage of `await` keyword twice. With the first usage, I set `continueOnCapturedContext` parameter of the `Task.ConfigureAwait` method to `false`. So, this indicates that I **don't necessarily want** my continuation to be executed inside the `SynchronizationContext.Current`. So far so good.

At the second `await` usage (with the `GetStringAsync` method), I didn't call the `ConfigureAwait` method. So, I basically indicated that I **want** to get back to current synchronization context for the continuation of the `GetStringAsync` method. So, as you can see, I try to set the `TextBlock.Text` (which belongs to UI thread) property inside the continuation.

When I run the application and click the button, I get an exception giving me the following message:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

At first, this made no sense to me and I thought that I discovered a bug but then, I realized that `GetStringAsync` may be executed in another thread (highly likely) which is different than the UI thread and has no knowledge for the sync context because the `continueOnCapturedContext` is set to `false` for the `Task` which is returned from `httpClient.GetAsync` method.

Is this the case here? Also, in this case, is there a chance for `GetStringAsync` method to be posted back to UI thread bacuse the httpClient.GetAsync method continuation may be executed inside the UI thread?

I have also a few comments inside the code. In view of my questions and the comments inside the code, am I missing anything here?

Comment: Does this answer help?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12357113/171121

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `ConfigureAwait(false)`, the rest of the method will be executed on a thread pool thread *unless* the `Task` you're `await`ing is already complete.

Since `GetAsync` will almost definitely run asynchronously, I would expect `GetStringAsync` to run on a thread pool thread.

```
public async Task<string> GetValuesAsync() {           

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {

        var response = await httpClient
            .GetAsync("http://www.google.com")
            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

        // And now we're on the thread pool thread.

        // This "await" will capture the current SynchronizationContext...
        var html = await GetStringAsync();
        // ... and resume it here.

        // But it's not the UI SynchronizationContext.
        // It's the ThreadPool SynchronizationContext.
        // So we're back on a thread pool thread here.

        // So this will raise an exception.
        html += "Hey...";
        Foo.Text = html;

        return html;
    }
}
```

> Also, in this case, is there a chance for GetStringAsync method to be posted back to UI thread bacuse the httpClient.GetAsync method continuation may be executed inside the UI thread?

The only way `GetStringAsync` will run on the UI thread is if `GetAsync` completes before it's actually `await`ed. *Highly* unlikely.

For this reason, I prefer to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for *every* `await` once the context is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks! Your last sentence is the way I consider following (I have been but now I am going to insist more on that). this is not gonna make noticeable difference but using `ConfigureAwait(false)` will also save us from unnecessary `SynchronizationContext` checks if it is not needed.

Comment: "Highly unlikely" is not enough, of course. Either it must be 100% or your code needs to tolerate both cases.

Comment: I agree in general. That's why I prefer to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for every `await` once the context is no longer needed.

Comment: if i have an async method that has if(await FileExistAsync(fileName))  should I use ConfigureAwait(false) in FileExistAsync?

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras: You should decide for each method separately whether it should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I always structure my code so that either a method *always* uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` or it *never* uses `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Is it safe to say that if the method will not need the UI context after await, then I shall use ConfigureAwait(false) to all await calls?

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras: Yes.