# Behavior of setting ConfigureAwait and SynchronisationContext

Tags: c#, async-await, synchronizationcontext

In his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12933547/1536989) [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) explained that when `ConfigureAwait(false)` is called the rest of the method will be executed on a thread pool thread **unless the `Task` you're `await`ing is already complete.**

What is clear: If I use `ConfigureAwait(false)` everything executed after the asynchronous call will be executed on a thread pool thread and therefore not run in the UI SynchronizationContext, otherwise (escpecially needed for UI based things like `textBox1.Text = data.Property`) it runs within UI SynchronizationContext.

What I don't understand is: Does `await` not mean that the `Task` I am waiting for is *always* completed before the methods is going on? So how can the Task not be completed before going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine something like this

```
var task = obj.SomeTaskAsync();
// do some lengthy computation
var value = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I think it's easy to see that the task could be completed even before the `await task` call.

In this case the code after the await will be executed in the same context, even if you have used `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Comment: Thank you, Dirk! Ok, alright I got it! Always only imagined on things like `var result = await DoSomething().ConfigureAwait(false);`. But does this not mean if calling something like my example my task is *always* completed before executing the rest of the method and should thereby executed in the UI SynchronisationContext?

Comment: Yes, but you should not rely on that. If you *want* to use execute the code after `await` on the same context as the call to the async method then don't use `.ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to write this code like this: `var task = obj.SomeTaskAsync();
/* do some lengthy computation */
var value = await task.ConfigureAwait(false);` That's because `ConfigureAwait()` makes sense only together with `await`.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand the precendence order. In particular, the dot operator (`.`) is of higher priority than `await`. So, when you do:

```
await SomeMethodAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

That's identical to:

```
var task = SomeMethodAsync();
var awaitable = task.ConfigureAwait(false);
await awaitable;
```

So, the `ConfigureAwait` is evaluated before the `await` expression, which actually does the (asynchronous) waiting.